# Akka Streams, what happens with the buffer after you call shutdown on the killingSwitch? DSL Graph

Tags: akka-stream

I have a `DLS graph` that is connected to `rabbitMQ`. (source and sink)

If I start the service with 10 messages already in the queue and value of `akka.stream.materializer.max-input-buffer-size` is 1, and I trigger the `killingSwitch` after one message is processed and another one is in-flight, it seems that I lose the message that is in the `akka-streams` buffer. (the stream does not shutdown until all the jobs that are in-flight complete)

I end-up with 7 messages remaining in the queue.

Any idea how that buffer works? or how to get access to that buffer? or how to process that message at well?

**ex**:
**start queue messages**
5646245d2b0000251a9fe92b
56def590430000fd1dac3e47
**542560eae4b0ba04ec469e12** (the messages that will get lost)
55835213e4b03eb77098e88e
569edf2851000098027fdad8
6cb975919f254472b61c012d0b76e119
53667258e4b09a003032bcb3
92e4765c5dae4c8485b0a3aa088b8c1b
5326b1c4e4b0b5ce16824303
5623f7912c000072223bc3af

**acknowledge messages**
5646245d2b0000251a9fe92b
56def590430000fd1dac3e47
**542560eae4b0ba04ec469e12** (lost message)

**processed messages**
5646245d2b0000251a9fe92b
56def590430000fd1dac3e47

**the messages in rabbitMQ buffer that are requeued**
55835213e4b03eb77098e88e

**messages left in the queue**
55835213e4b03eb77098e88e
569edf2851000098027fdad8
6cb975919f254472b61c012d0b76e119
53667258e4b09a003032bcb3
92e4765c5dae4c8485b0a3aa088b8c1b
5326b1c4e4b0b5ce16824303
5623f7912c000072223bc3af